# Karma - config file does not exist

Tags: node.js, angularjs, npm, karma-runner

Hi I'm trying to go through the AngularJS [original tutorial](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_02) and in step 2 where I'm supposed to run ./scripts/test.sh, I get an error saying

```
[ERROR] config - Config file does not exist!
```

I've checked /config/karma.conf.js and the file indeed does exist.

I'm running the latest version of node, npm, and karma.

I thought re-installing them would fix the issue (as mentioned by a member of the AngularJS team on a Google forum [post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/karma-users/Od0kZcPTHY0) I found).

I still get the error however. Anyone have any suggestions?

Edit: I tried running /config/karma.conf.js and it gave an error saying "JASMINE is undefined," even though Jasmine is installed. Do I have to set a path or something? I have jasmine installed globally.

Comment: There isn't any rellevant information here. You might want to try if karma is really in the path and works. Start it manually with `karma start config/karma.conf.js`. can you show an `ls -l` of your project directory?

Answer (score 3):

You might need to install Karma

steps:

1. npm install generator-karma
2. yo karma

Answer (score 1):

If you are on windows try to run ./scripts/test.bat.

Answer (score 1):

On Mac OS Mavericks.

1 - Install Karma

```
npm install -g generator-karma
```

2 - run yo karma

```
yo karma
```

If node.js and yo is working this will be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `ng generate config karma`?

That solved my problem, I didn't have the config file at all.
Now it has created the `Karma.config.js` file

- More in [Karma Runner GitHub](https://karma-runner.github.io/latest/intro/installation.html)